# NEO4J CREATE RELATIONSHIP ON LOAD CSV

Tags: neo4j

I'm new to Neo4j and trying to create a relationship between existing nodes ... in this case Artist & Album.
I have loaded both without issue as follows:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///chinook/artist.csv" AS line
CREATE (:Artist {artistid: toInteger(line.ArtistId), name: line.Name})
```

&

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///chinook/album.csv" AS line
CREATE (:Album {albumid: toInteger(line.AlbumId), title: line.Title, artistid: toInteger(line.ArtistId)})
```

You can see artistid is common to both node types and this is what I'm attempting to create the relationship on.

I have tried multiple ways to get this to work but it's just not working as I expect. E.g.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///chinook/artist.csv" AS line
MATCH (al:Album {artistd: line.ArtistId})
MATCH (ar:Artist {artistd: line.ArtistId})
CREATE (ar)-[:RELEASED]->(al)
```

&

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///chinook/artist.csv" AS line
match (ar:Artist), (al:Album) 
where ar.artistid = line.ArtistId and 
      al.artistid = line.ArtistId
MERGE (ar)-[:RELEASED]->(al)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction ? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your query is `artistd` is **integer** in your database and you are matching it with `artistd` which is **string** in the following query.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///chinook/artist.csv" AS line
MATCH (al:Album {artistd: line.ArtistId})
MATCH (ar:Artist {artistd: line.ArtistId})
CREATE (ar)-[:RELEASED]->(al)
```

You need to convert to integer while matching as shown:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///chinook/artist.csv" AS line
MATCH (al:Album {artistd: toInteger(line.ArtistId)})
MATCH (ar:Artist {artistd: toInteger(line.ArtistId)})
MERGE (ar)-[:RELEASED]->(al)
```

**Suggestion:**

You don't need to store `artistd` as a property of **Album** node, just `albumid` will work. In this case, you need to Match **Album** on `albumid` field.